# How to set app icon in the .desktop file of an Ubuntu Touch application?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

I am learning the Ubuntu SDK, and I have make an new HTML5 Touch UI project with Qt Creator.

The project folder has an `.desktop` file. I then added an `launcher.png` to my project's folder.

Here is my `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=myapp
StartupNotify=true
Icon=/usr/share/myapp/launcher.png
MimeType=text/plain;
NoDisplay=true
Comment=something...
Exec=/usr/bin/qmlscene $@ /usr/share/myapp/diaspora-webclient.qml
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-Ubuntu-Touch=true
```

Now I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to run the app with `qmlscene`. The app runs, but `launcher.png` is not displayed as the app's icon in the Unity Launcher.

Do I need to run an command to update the changes? Or do I need to move the `launcher.png` to `/usr/share/myapp/launcher.png` via in-app-code?

Comment: You need to set the *real* path to the image. For testing purposes you can set it to be the path inside your development structure. Notice that moving the file to `/usr/share` would require you to type your password each time. Another alternative is to simply put a copy of the icon in `~/.icons`.

Comment: Make sure that you have permissions to read the file.

Comment: Ok... so there is not any standard path where icons should be placed?

Comment: Already told you, you can put them on `~/.icons` (for testing purposes).

Comment: Yes but only for testing purposes,.. right..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are two things wrong with how you're doing things.

Fist of all, `.desktop` files are intended for installed apps, not for running via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. To install your app, you need to package it and install the package. You can find more details about packaging your app and publishing it in the Click App Store [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/343877/109543).

Second of all, the paths you have in the `.desktop` should be local files, not absolute paths. Here is an example of a `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Tasks
Comment=Your tasks, every device, everywhere.
Exec=qmlscene $@ ubuntu-tasks.qml
Icon=ubuntu-tasks.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-Ubuntu-Touch=true
```

A couple of things to note:

- The `Exec` line should be in the format of `qmlscene $@ <file.qml>`, with just the name of your main QML file, no directory information.
- The `Icon` line should be in the form of `Icon=<icon.png>`, with just the file name (including the extension), no directory information.

Now the information I've provided above is for running your app on an Ubuntu Touch device by packaging it in a Click package. Click packages are intended for Ubuntu Touch and currently don't integrate with the Unity desktop. So, if you want to be able to run your app from the Dash/Launcher and also see its icon, you will need to do two things:

1. Copy your `.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applications` and use an absolute path to your icon instead of just the file name, as you would when packaging the app.
2. Copy your icon to `~/.icons`

Comment: Great! It also seems, that the *.png-file is supposed to have the same width as its height is and not exceed 512px on any side (at least for me a regular png-image was not resized properly as a icon; downsizing and extending it to be quadratic (512x512px) helped).

Comment: To make it works on Ubuntu 20.04, I've to copy the .png file into the `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps` folder instead of the pointed out here.

Comment: I could fix the missing icon problem by creating the folder ~/.icons and copying there my icon's PNG file.

Answer (score 0):

**Desktop Version:** For me in **Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop** the icon of Squeezeplay was not showing up, neither in the search window, nor in the gnome3 side dock panel.

The solution [above](https://askubuntu.com/a/344062/322100) worked from **@iBelieve** for me showing up an icon in the search dialog, but not in the gnome side panel.

Adding the *StartupWMClass=jive* (found out clicking the opened application using `xprop WM_CLASS` in the cli)to the desktop file from the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1262508/322100) completed the Mission, now I can see everywhere (search dialog, pressing "Windows" key and gnome dock side panel) the provided icon file (png file format, max size 512x512, I choose 256x256)! The desktop file was generated like:

`$ vim ~/.local/applications/squeezeplay.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Squeezeplay
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
Comment=https://sourceforge.net/projects/lmsclients/files/squeezeplay/linux/ The Linux version of Squeezelite-X (similar) working with LMS
Exec=/opt/squeezeplay/bin/squeezeplay.sh
Icon=squeezeplay-icon2-256x256.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=jive
Categories=Utility;Radio;
```

Like explained the icon was stored in `~/.icons` directory with the name given in `Icon=`! Thanks to @iBelieve and @Puspam!